# Deserialise Json file with newtonsoft and query with linq

Tags: c#, parsing, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm new to Newtonsoft and I'm trying to deserialise my json file then query specific data points from it. Here is a sample of the json.

```
[
    {
        "reward_type": "1",
        "rejected": "0",
        "user_id": "538653",
        "granted": "0"
    },
    {
        "reward_type": "5",
        "rejected": "0",
        "user_id": "536345",
        "granted": "1"
    },
    {
        "reward_type": "5",
        "rejected": "0",
        "user_id": "539493",
        "granted": "1"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to query the values after each type. I've been trying to wrap my head around the documentation for Json.net for a few days, but I'm having trouble finding examples for deserializing files.

Here is what I've been using to parse the file.

```
InitializeComponent();
        JArray adData1 = JArray.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\ads.json"));
        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"c:\ads.json"))
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            JArray adData2 = (JArray)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(JArray));

            JObject rewardType = (JObject)adData2[1];
            label1.Text = rewardType.ToString();
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet (IMHO) is to deserialize into a DTO/POCO object (simple c# class with just basic properties on it) and then linq query against it/them.  See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: You could use anonymous types I guess.  Harder to maintain IMHO : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm

Comment: Your JSON sample appears to be missing the enclosing square brackets `[]` that would make it a valid array of objects.  If the brackets are actually present in the overall JSON, you should show them in your question.  If they are not there, then your JSON is invalid, and that could be part of the reason you are having trouble parsing it.

Comment: The [] brackects are there, it's just the json it 20k lines and just decided to take a sample of it, thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 1):

From the suggestions:

Its only useable if the data have a common structure. You can Replace the DataTypes in the POCO, if you like

The POCO

```
public class Stuff {
    public string reward_type { get; set; }
    public string rejected { get; set; }
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string granted { get; set; }
}
```

How to use:

```
public void doThings() { 
// var s = File.ReadAllText("yourfilename.json");
    var s = @"{
""reward_type"": ""1"",
""rejected"": ""0"",
""user_id"": ""538653"",
""granted"": ""0""
},
{
""reward_type"": ""5"",
""rejected"": ""0"",
""user_id"": ""536345"",
""granted"": ""1""
},
{
""reward_type"": ""5"",
""rejected"": ""0"",
""user_id"": ""539493"",
""granted"": ""1""
}";
    // [] is needed to make it recognize it as list
    var listOfStuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stuff>>("["+s+"]");
    foreach (var item in listOfStuff)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.user_id);
    }

}
```